# Logarithmic Decay Function

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions

I have been trying to determine a function that will give a logarithmic decay that has the following characteristics:

[image: Logarithmic Decay Graph]

Where variable $a$ would be the y-intercept, and variable $b$ would be the x-intercept. Variable $d$ would be the % decay. I have fiddled around with various flavours of logarithmic functions, but have still been unable to reproduce the desired graph.

Comment: What's logarithmic about it?

Comment: Did you try fiddling with something like $y = A - Be^{kx}$?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).